# Unable to connect to AWS services form EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have created an EKS cluster using `eksctl`. I am following these steps to establish connectivity to AWS services like S3, cloudwatch using spring-boot.

1. Create EKS using `eksctl` - This has my service account details and OIDC enabled.
2. List the service accounts to see if they were created fine
3. Create a deployment using the account name
4. Create a service

I am seeing a 403 in the logs:

```
User: arn:aws:sts:xxx/xxxx is not authorized to perform: 
cloudformation:DescribeStackResources because no identity-based policy allows 
the cloudformation:DescribeStackResources action (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 403; 
Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: xxxx)
```

Can I get some help here to troubleshoot this issue, please?

---

What I have figured out after posting this issue is my node which is provisioned by `eksctl`, has been applied with rules. This is the rule which my app is picking up due to the default CredentialChain.

What I haven't still figured out is how do I enable the apps in the pod to assume a service account role.

---

##### YAML for #1

```
---
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig

metadata:
  name: name
  region: ap-south-1

availabilityZones: ["xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx"]

managedNodeGroups:
- name: c5large-nodes
  desiredCapacity: 1
  instanceType: c5.large
  labels:
    node-type: large
  volumeSize: 5


cloudWatch:
  clusterLogging:
    enableTypes: [ "*" ]

iam:
  withOIDC: true
  serviceAccounts:
    - metadata:
        name: cluster-autoscaler
        namespace: kube-system
        labels: {aws-usage: "autoscaling"}
      wellKnownPolicies:
        autoScaler: true
      roleName: eksctl-cluster-autoscaler-role
      roleOnly: true
    - metadata:
        name: backend-stage-iam-role
        namespace: backend-stage
        labels: { aws-usage: "all-backend-allow" }
      attachPolicyARNs:
        - "arn:aws:iam::xxxx"
    - metadata:
        name: mq-access
        namespace: backend-stage
        labels: { aws-usage: "MQ" }
      attachPolicyARNs:
        - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonMQFullAccess"
```

##### YAML for deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: my-app
  namespace: backend-stage
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: backend-stage-iam-role
      containers:
        - image: xxx/my-app:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: my-app
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
              value: stage
```

##### YAML for service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: backend-stage
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
   -  protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

The role is defined like this for now:

```
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - cloudformation:*
            Resource: "*"
```

I did further debugging, by describing the pod, I can see the role passed as an ENV parameter:

````
AWS_ROLE_ARN:                 arn:aws:iam::MYACCOUNT:role/MyRole```
````

Answer (score 0):

Just add missing permission to arn:aws:sts:xxx/xxxx assumed role.

Comment: This was created by `eksctl`, I am trying to add another role that will increase the access level of this deployment. What am I missing here?

Comment: Another problem with this approach is, while deleting the cluster this role can't de deleted as it as another policy attached which isn't managed by eksctl.